# Is there an existing data structure that is applicable for all kinds of different history events?

Tags: java, data-structures, amazon-dynamodb

My team is trying to build a feature that saves all the actions in our system into dynamoDB. And these actions are quite different: they shared some common fields, however, some of other fields are different. Is there an existing data structure that is applicable for all kinds of different history events? (PS: our team uses Java)

It would be good if there exists an open source one that I can borrow some ideas from.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you try to reframe your question? I don't understand.

Comment: There isn't even universal agreement amongst historians; no, there is no silver bullet for historical events.

Comment: ...but, you can come up with some schema with all the common fields, and use, for instance, a `Map` for the dynamic ones. I use event-sourcing and that's the approach I took. It plays nice most of the times.

Comment: So, your team has the perfect tech stack for the feature! DynamoDB doesn't require a pre-defined schema and on the Java side, you can write a base class that has the common fields and **N** other class specializations(or a Map). It's probably a good idea if your team come up with a data structure that fits well your needs.

Comment: You could also follow the example of [SWF History Event][https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_HistoryEvent.html] where each event type has its own attributes object field.